# Can't edit/drag-and-drop widgets in QtCreator

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt4, qt-creator

I am having a slightly bizarre problem and am not sure what is happening so maybe someone else has seen it and could throw some light on the issue.

I have Qt 4.6.1 installed in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x64 that is running as a virtual guest (VirtualBox) in Windows 7 x32.

Anyway... I have created a new widget and it won't let me edit it or drag widgets onto it. It is almost like it is read-only. The icon when I drag is a circle with a line through it. I have seen mention of a drag-drop problem with Windows 7 but I have tried that fix and it doesn't change anything.

Everything builds and runs, just cannot use the designer at all.

Comment: Did I understand well, that you created your OWN widget for designer (with plugin)? If yes, then `bool QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface::isContainer () const` for your widget plugin must return true to be able to put another widgets inside

Comment: It's widgets created from within QtCreator itself that are not working. Widgets that I already had and work fine on Qt in other environments don't work either. So I am now suspecting it is an issue with Ubuntu for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will help someone else who may have the problem as I have found a solution, although not an ideal one.

Basically it seems there might be an issue with the new Unity shell and Qt. I needed to change the shell to gnome and it works now.

In terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

Then logged out and switched to Gnome shell and now dragging-and-dropping works. I don't know if the issue is within Virtualbox, Ubuntu 12.04 or Qt